# React and Meteor "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've seen the question asked before, and I've done everything that has been suggested:

- remove the curly brackets from the import statement of the component
- imported React without the curly brackets
- I've tried it with the curly brackets

index.hmtl

```
<head>
    <title>My ChatApp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

index.js

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import ChatComponent from "../../ui/App";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<ChatComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
});
```

App.js

```
import { React, Component } from "react";

class ChatComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Try Chatting</h1>;
  }
}

export default ChatComponent;
```

I'm still getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined" from the App.js file at line 9 which is the "return" line.  It will work if I change the ChatComponent to a function rather than a class, but react says in the documentation that it doesn't differentiate.  I've also tried commenting-out/removing-all-together the constructor part of the class with no effect. I'm kind of at a loss why this is not working. Why won't it work as a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `App.js` you want to use this import line for React:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

The reason why is that `jsx` syntax gets compiled into `React.createElement` calls.

So the error `Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined` tells you that `React` is undefined.

In the React package, `React` is the default export, so can't be imported in the curly braces